# Excel: I copy pasted list 200 links from website to Excel and I want to extract text from the link

Tags: excel

The links appear hyperlinked with blue line in Excel,  I want to extract the text from the link e.g.
The url http:\sea.craigslist.com appears as "seattle"  in excel. I want to extract the text "sea" out of the link and paste in a next column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a user defined function (UDF) to extract the data.

- Open your workbook.
- Open the VBA Editor by pressing Alt+F11
- Insert a new module by using the menu *Insert -> Module*
- Copy and paste in the function code listed below
- Close the VBA Editor by using the menu *File -> Close and return to Microsoft Excel*
- Assuming the first link is in cell A1, in cell B1 type in the formula =GetPart(A1)
- Copy the formula down as required

The formula should return the value 'sea' in cell B1

```
Function GetPart(cell As Range) As String

    Dim iStart As Integer
    Dim iEnd As Integer
    Dim iLen As Integer

        If (cell.Range("A1").Hyperlinks.Count <> 1) Then
            GetPart = ""
        Else
            GetPart = cell.Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Address
            iStart = InStr(1, GetPart, "//") + 2
            iEnd = InStr(1, GetPart, ".")
            iLen = iEnd - iStart
            GetPart = Mid(GetPart, iStart, iLen)
        End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(C3,LEN(C3)-7),FIND(".",RIGHT(C3,LEN(C3)-7))-1)
```

Paste this code in the cell where you want the "sea" to be. Replace C3 in the above code with the cell that has link like http://sea.something.com. It'll display sea in the result cell.

**Note:** This will only work if your link has "http://" in the beginning of the link.

Comment: in excel cell the link does not appear as "http://sea.something.com" instead it appears as "sea" which hyperlinks to "http://sea.something.com" will it work even then.

Comment: Type this in the result cell "=C3", here C3 is the cell that contains the link, and you're done :)

Answer (score 0):

For this you can take help of  VBA programming in excel.
you can get lots of pdf and tuts regarding it.

http://www.adnug.com/book_reviews/Programming%20Excel%20with%20VBA%20_3_.pdf